# Pasar un array a una vista en cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

tengo un array de esta manera realizando un var_drum.

```
array (size=1)
  'articles' => 
    array (size=36)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[134]
          public 'id' => int 56
          public 'title' => string 'prueba con servicio json es tt aa' (length=33)
          public 'body' => string 'prueba de hoy' (length=13)
          public 'created' => string '2018-06-22T19:49:34+00:00' (length=25)
          public 'modified' => string '2018-06-22T19:49:34+00:00' (length=25)
```

y quiero pasar este array en un foreach en una vista de cakephp

el controlador lo tengo de esta manera

```
public function index()
{

$http = new Client();
$response = $http->get('http://localhost/paginaws/articles/index.json');
$json = $response->json;
$json = $response->body;
$jarray = json_decode($json);
//$jarray = json_decode( json_encode( $json ), true );
$valor = (array)$jarray;


$this->set(compact(['valor']));


}
```

Comment: es var_dump()..

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿En qué estás fallando?

Comment: Quiero que esos valores del array se vean en la vista index.ctp de cakephp.

Comment: ¿Cómo lo estás pasando desde la vista al controlador?

Comment: public function index()
 {

 $http = new Client();
 $response = $http->get('http://localhost/paginaws/articles/index.json');
 $json = $response->json;
 $json = $response->body;
 $jarray = json_decode($json);
 //$jarray = json_decode( json_encode( $json ), true );
 $valor = (array)$jarray;
 
  
 $this->set(compact(['valor']));

   
 }

Comment: ya actualice la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizarlo como cualquier arreglo de PHP, ten en cuenta que los valores del arreglo son objetos por lo que tendrás que acceder a sus propiedades mediante `->`

En tu index.ctp

```
<?php foreach ($valor['articles'] as $article): ?>
    <h1><?php echo $article->title ?></h1>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: super si me funciono, gracias